# How To Put App Info In Settings Menu

Tags: ios, settings, system

A lot of apps have extra info under the iOS Settings menu.

How can I get my app a slot under the settings menu? 
How to put the info in?

I haven't been able to find any info on this.

Comment: Have you been able to achieve it?

Comment: @GenieWanted sorry haven't gotten around to it -- give me a couple of days...I'm only working on my project in the very little bit of spare time that I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to take a look at  [Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) . This basically allows you to set preferences/settings of your app in the main settings page.

A simple video tut on the same: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUa2UiaUANk

http://www.sivamuthukumar.net/2013/05/custom-settings-bundle-to-ios-app.html

Comment: any other videos that aren't on youtube? youtube is blocked where I'm at.

Comment: Hmmm.. the other link I've mentioned above also gives you easy-to-follow steps. Perhaps, another step by step tutorial I can think of.  http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/application-setting-in-iphone/